# Почему не работает функция объединения двух массивов в js

Tags: javascript

Что имеем:

1. Есть несколько массивов со вложенными объектами по типу (переменные flowers, cats, cars):

```
сonst cats = [{
  'id': 'YdAqiUkUoWA',
  'url': 'img/cats-1.jpg',
  'description': '',
}, {
  'id': 'hX_hf2lPpUU',
  'url': 'img/cats-2.jpg',
  'description': '',
}, {
  'id': 'w1JE5duY62M',
  'url': 'img/cats-3.jpg',
  'description': '',
}
```

2. Есть объект cо ссылками:

```
 const imageCollection = {
      flowers, cats, cars,
    };
```

3. Надо написать функцию для формирования набора изображений. Функция получает параметр с темой картинок и должна сформировать набор из пар картинок. Для парных картинок нужно сгенерировать id объекта. Идентификаторы должны быть уникальными. Для этого достаточно добавить один знак к оригинальному id, например, { id: `${item.id}-1` }.

Почему такой способ написания фунции у меня не работает?

```
const getImages = (type) => {
  let secondArr = [...imageCollection[type]]
  secondArr = secondArr.map(item => {
    return {...item, id: item.id + '-1'};
  });
  let newArr = [...imageCollection[type], ...secondArr];
  return newArr;
}
```

При этом вот такой способ работает:
c

```
onst getImages = (type) => {
  const imageSet = imageCollection[type];
  const newArr = [];
  imageSet.forEach((item) => {
    const pair1 = { id: `${item.id}-1`, url: item.url, description: item.description };
    const pair2 = { id: `${item.id}-2`, url: item.url, description: item.description };
    newArr.push(pair1, pair2);
  });
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле и первый вариант рабочий. Можешь (если очень смущает) деструкторизацию массива заменить на slice()
https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-wave-d429yx?file=/src/App.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]